# Struggling to read value from web.config file using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"] in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Struggling to read value from web.config file using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"].

Using ASp .Net v5 and C#

**WEb.config file**:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v5.0" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="dbconnectionstring" value="mongodb://sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg"/>
    <add key="Databasename" value="WineSales"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Request and reading code:**

```
[HttpPost("customer/addCustomer")]
    public IActionResult AddCustomer([FromBody] DTO_IN_Customer customerData)
{

    var yeet = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconnectionstring"];

    System.Console.WriteLine(yeet); 

    var result = _salesPersonService.AddCustomer(customerData);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Is there somethign I am missing, because everywhere I searched they are doing it this way and when I put a breakpoint at var result then `yeet` is empty.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the web.config file to app.config and then it should work